# Curious output using formatC with 2 significant digits

Tags: r, format, significant-digits

I want to format figures with 2 significant digits using `formatC`. But it has a strange behaviour. Here are the figures:

```
(x <- data.frame(  cil = c(1.234, 0.444, 0.712, 0.999, 1.999)
                 , ciu = c(1.812, 1.234, 0.999, 1.199, 2.690)
                 )
 )
 
x$ci <- with(x,paste("("
              , formatC(cil, format="g", digits=2, flag="#")
              , "-"
              , formatC(ciu, format="g", digits=2, flag="#")
              ,")"
                      )
              )
x
```

And here are the results:

```
      cil   ciu         ci
1     1.234 1.812  ( 1.2 - 1.8 )
2     0.444 1.234 ( 0.44 - 1.2 )
3     0.712 0.999 ( 0.71 - 1.0 )
4     0.999 1.199  ( 1.0 - 1.2 )
5     1.999 2.690  (  2. - 2.7 )
```

In case 5 I expected **2.0** and not **2.**. Is there an explanation for this? Did I something wrong with the definition of the parameters?

New curious behaviour: leading space depending if figure was rounded down or up:

```
y1 <- 18.96552
y2 <- 17.04545
formatC(y1, format="g", digits=2,flag="#")
[1] "  19."
formatC(y2, format="g", digits=2,flag="#")
"17."
```

Can be solved with trim (from gdata). But anyway, it is a strange behaviour as the first one, which by the way persists (V4.32).

Comment: maybe it does'nt really answer your question but you can use `format` with `nsmall` : `format(1.999, digits=2, nsmall=2)` gives you `"2.00"` (which I actually find better than `"2.0"` when you're displaying values rounded to the 2nd decimal)

Comment: @giordano I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @giordano Could you show the R version? I am using `R 3.1.2`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for help. My version is: R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10).

Comment: @giordano There might be some changes with each upgrade.  It may be best to try it on the new version.  BTW, I am using it on linux.

Comment: @akrun I tried also with R version 3.1.2 on Windows 7 (the former was also Windows 7). Maybe it has to be something to with the OS.

Comment: @giordano May be, I am not sure.

Comment: @giordano You could use regex too to solve the problem.  Please check my update.

Comment: @akrun Yes, you'r right. I wanted to avoid this and I'was wondering if I didn't get the concept of significant digits or if I didn't use the correct way to formatC. Obviously, since on linux you got the expected value, it has to do with Windows 7. Which is also curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate what I was saying in my comment, you can do :

```
x$ci<-with(x,paste("(",
                   format(cil,digits=2,nsmall=2),
                   "-",
                   format(ciu,digits=2,nsmall=2),")"))
> x
  case   cil   ciu              ci
1    A 1.234 1.812 ( 1.23 - 1.81 )
2    B 0.444 1.234 ( 0.44 - 1.23 )
3    C 0.712 0.999 ( 0.71 - 1.00 )
4    D 0.999 1.199 ( 1.00 - 1.20 )
5    E 1.999 2.690 ( 2.00 - 2.69 )
```

or the following, to suppress the spaces before or after the brackets :

```
x$ci<-with(x,paste0("(",
                    format(cil,digits=2,nsmall=2),
                    " - ",
                    format(ciu,digits=2,nsmall=2),")"))
> x
  case   cil   ciu          ci
1    A 1.234 1.812 (1.23 - 1.81)
2    B 0.444 1.234 (0.44 - 1.23)
3    C 0.712 0.999 (0.71 - 1.00)
4    D 0.999 1.199 (1.00 - 1.20)
5    E 1.999 2.690 (2.00 - 2.69)
```

**NB** : you actually can get the same result using function `formatC` but with `format="f"` instead of `"g"`.

**UPDATE :**

I guess the fact that `0` is not printed after `2.` is just a bug in some R versions (weirder thing : if you try the line with `2.01` instead of `1.999`, you'll get `"2.0"`...).

To make it work with your line and obtain exactly what you want, just add `round` function :

```
x$ci<-with(x,paste("(",
                    formatC(round(cil,2), format="g", digits=2, flag="#"),
                   "-",
                   formatC(round(ciu,2), format="g", digits=2, flag="#"),")"))

> x
  case   cil   ciu             ci
1    A 1.234 1.812  ( 1.2 - 1.8 )
2    B 0.444 1.234 ( 0.44 - 1.2 )
3    C 0.712 0.999 ( 0.71 - 1.0 )
4    D 0.999 1.199  ( 1.0 - 1.2 )
5    E 1.999 2.690  ( 2.0 - 2.7 )
```

Comment: To get to the result you showed, it is not that difficult.  Please check my update.

Comment: @CathG. Thanks for help and for this alternative. Nevertheles, I would like to know how it becomes that I get **2.** and not **2.0**.

Comment: @CathG which version of R you are using?

Comment: @giordano : see my update, it doesn't explain the bug but permit to get what you want in spite of it...

Comment: @CathG Obviously, it is a bug. Thanks a lot for this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Using `R 3.1.2` on `linux mint 17`, I couldn't reproduce the problem as I am getting the exact result as your expected output. But, here is an option to use `paste` along with `do.call` in case you have many columns (or in general)

**1) Using formatC**

```
x$ci <- paste0("(",do.call(`paste`, c(lapply(x[,2:3], function(x) 
 formatC(x, format='g',   digits=2, flag='#')), list(sep=" - "))) ,")")
x$ci
#[1] "(1.2 - 1.8)"  "(0.44 - 1.2)" "(0.71 - 1.0)" "(1.0 - 1.2)"  "(2.0 - 2.7)"
```

Note: that the above is exactly the same expected output.

**2) Using sprintf**

Another option that I consider would be to use `sprintf` if you need similar output as @CathG showed before the update

```
x$ci <- paste0("(",do.call(`paste`, c(lapply(x[2:3], function(x) 
                       sprintf('%0.2f', x)), list(sep="-"))),")")
x$ci
#[1] "(1.23-1.81)" "(0.44-1.23)" "(0.71-1.00)" "(1.00-1.20)" "(2.00-2.69)"
```

#### Update

You could use `regex` to solve the problem.  For example, I created the `5th` entry as the same as your output and use  regex `lookbehind`

```
x$ci[5] <- "( 2. - 2.7 )"
sub('(?<=\\.) ', '0', x$ci, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "( 1.2 - 1.8 )"  "( 0.44 - 1.2 )" "( 0.71 - 1.0 )" "( 1.0 - 1.2 )" 
#[5] "( 2.0- 2.7 )"
```

Comment: this gives me the exact same result as with the OP's code : `"( 1.2-1.8 )"  "( 0.44-1.2 )" "( 0.71-1.0 )" "( 1.0-1.2 )"  "(  2.-2.7 )"` (which is not that surprising)

Comment: @akrun Thanks for this version using lapply. As expected I got the same result as using my version. Nevertheless, it's a good idea to use your version especially if there a lot of columns to format in the same way.

Comment: @akrun it seems that I have to use the workaround with regex to cope with the "bug". Thanks!